# React Native View shrinks to fit content when centered

Tags: css, react-native

I have a React Native `View` that I would like to have extend up to but not exceed a given width. Inside this `View`, I have a `Text` element that I would like to fill out the full width of its parent. It looks like this:
[image: No Alignment Set]

However, if I set the parent `View` to center align with `alignSelf: 'center'` the view will shrink to fit the text inside the `Text` view, like so:
[image: Center Alignment Set]

Why does changing the alignment of a `View` cause it to change size, and how can I prevent this?

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Complete code to replicate this scenario:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Text</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  box: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height: 50,
    maxWidth:200,
    alignSelf: 'center'  // <---REMOVE THIS LINE TO FILL VIEW
  },
  paragraph: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});
```

**Why adding width will not work**

While setting a fixed `width` value would enforce the maximum size, it would prevent this element from shrinking down below that value. For this reason, specifying `width` is not a solution. Here is an example situation where the size of the view would extend past the display.

With width:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why centering a div causes the size of the element to change... shouldn't it just... center?

Comment: what you want to get?

Comment: @yoel I'm trying to have the first picture, but centered instead of on the left.

Comment: @CyrusZei Yes, it's centered because I told it to. Is my question unclear? The title isn't asking why it's centering, it's why the size changes.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add both `maxWidth: 200` and `width: "100%"`. Then the width will expand to be as wide as possible, but remain constrained to a maximum of 200.

```
  box: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height: 50,
    maxWidth:200,
    width: '100%',
    alignSelf: 'center'  // <---REMOVE THIS LINE TO FILL VIEW
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Text</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent:'center',//ADD THIS LINE
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  box: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height: 50,
    maxWidth:200,
  },
  paragraph: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});
```

[expo](https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/quiet-tortillas)

Comment: Adding in `width` will force the element to the expected maximum size, but prevents the element from shrinking to a lower size.

Comment: I removed width

Comment: That brings us back to the original problem.

Comment: hi @Software2  add ``alignContent:'center',`` in  ``container`` style

Comment: `alignContent` of the parent and `alignSelf` of the child element are functionally equivalent in this scenario. But just to be sure, I ran your code on Snack, and it's doing the same thing as my code.

Comment: @Software2 Sorry but still did not understand what you are interested in getting exactly?

Comment: I added an image to represent the expected output.

Comment: @Software2  excellent!
But why do not you want to give it width?

Comment: If the outer view (container style) is smaller than the inner view (box style), this will cause the text to be cut off, rather than fit to the size of the outer view. An example scenario where this can occur would be a phone screen of insufficient size.

To try this yourself in the default Snack iOS device, add a few sentences to the text field, and set the maxWidth and width to 500, and then add/remove the alignment. You'll see the view will either extend beyond the sides of the phone, or fit to it with the specified 8 padding.

Comment: @Software2 ok get it     ``flex: 0.5,`` in box style  ``flexDirection:'row',``
in container style, see here https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/quiet-tortillas  That way he will always get only half a screen